# Open source CSS generator

Tags: css, open-source

Is there any open source/free CSS-style generator. What I am looking for is to be able to apply styles through UI, see a preview of styles applied on an element and when I am satisfied, get the CSS code generated for that combination.

Comment: @BoltClock I am using webapps, but styling is an essential part of making app look different. I am using GWT as UI technology in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.csswizard.net/  also you have demo and tutorials there, you can add elements, edit code... have a try. This one still requires registration but this is in case when you need more templates or more functions, otherwise it might be a good software to work with.